# Using math functions to get integer values

Tags: javascript, css, less

I have some LessCSS that essentially looks like this:

```
.foo {
    @height: 20px;
    @iconHeight: 13px;

    background-position: 0 (@height - @iconHeight) / 2;
}
```

However, this obviously turns out as `background-position: 0 3.5px`, and I'd prefer for it to be an integer (the value of `Math.ceil`), however this doesn't work:

```
background-position: 0 Math.ceil((@height - @iconHeight) / 2)
```

Nor does using the javascript evaluation operator:

```
background-position: 0 `Math.ceil((@height - @iconHeight) / 2)`
```

...since this is parsed as `Math.ceil(20px - 13px)` and the "px" there is a syntax error.

I've even tried using `parseInt`

```
0 `Math.ceil((parseInt('@{height}', 10) - parseInt('@{iconHeight}', 10)) / 2)`px
```

However this turns out like this:

```
background-position: 0 4 px
```

...which isn't right. And finally, even adding the "px" in the JS evaluation doesn't work

```
background-position: 0 `Math.ceil(....) + "px"`;
// becomes
background-position: 0 "4px";
```

Surely there's a better way!

Comment: **Update:** I've found the [`round`](https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/blob/master/dist/less-1.1.4.js#L1384) function which works for me in this specific case, however I'd still be interested to know if there was a general way to solve this problem.

Comment: IMHO in this case I would rethink the design and choose sizes that don't don't need to be rounded, because due to the rounding, the calculated values will be "off" anyway.

Comment: @RoToRa, *maybe* in this one case that is a better option, but in general the issue still remains.

Comment: Shouldn't the "/ 2" be inside the Math.ceil call in the first lines?
Meaining background-position: 0 Math.ceil((@height - @iconHeight) / 2)

Comment: @Tonio, ah yeah, you're right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a simple workaround to the problem using temporary variable and `0px` hack.

```
.foo {
    @height: 20px;
    @iconHeight: 13px;

    @result: `Math.ceil((parseInt('@{height}') - parseInt('@{iconHeight}')) / 2)`;
    background-position: 0 (0px + @result);
}
```